# How to construct and manipulate URI with native URL?

Tags: javascript

[MDN URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) supports constructing a URL with:

```
new URL('https://example.com/path/to/resource?query=param#hash')
new URL('/path/to/resource?query=param#hash', 'https://example.com')
```

My URI `/path/to/resource?query=param#hash` does not have base url.

My usage for URI is exactly the same as URL. Can I utilize native URL to do what I want? Basically, I want to:

```
// create a URI /path/to/resource
// set query parameters
// set hash
// return entire URI as string /path/to/resource?query=param#hash
```

If not, I would have to use an external library like [URI.js](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/).

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way to do it, but if you insist on using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), you can do something like:

```js
const yourUrl = new URL('/path/to/resource?query=param#hash', 'https://example.com')
console.log(yourUrl.href.replace(yourUrl.origin, ""));
```